# Numpy - How to vectorize on Sub-Arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

How do you apply vectorized functions on sub-arrays? Suppose I have the following:

```
array = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2],
    [],
])
```

And I wanted to obtain the first element in each subarray, else `None`.

`[0, 2, None]`

While simple, is there are way to do this leveraging Numpy's pure vectorization? There doesn't seem to be native operations, and the `np.vectorize()` function is described to not be true documentation and has been stated at various other points in threads.

Is my only option to do a `np.apply_along_axes()`?

When do I know when I cannot solve my problem with numpy's pure vectorization?

Comment: There's no true vectorization for this. Just loop through.

Comment: numpy does not allow you to have a non-rectangular array. what you are referring to as _sub-arrays_  will in fact be lists, in which you cannot use numpy tools beyond a simple loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an object dtype array - containing lists (not subarrays):

```
In [2]: array = np.array([ 
   ...:     [0, 1, 2], 
   ...:     [2], 
   ...:     [], 
   ...: ])                                                                      
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:4: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (1.19dev gives warning)
In [3]: array                                                                   
Out[3]: array([list([0, 1, 2]), list([2]), list([])], dtype=object)
```

We could use a list comprehension:

```
In [4]: [a[0] for a in array]                                                   
....
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and correcting for the empty list:

```
In [5]: [a[0] if a else None for a in array]                                    
Out[5]: [0, 2, None]
```

Most of the fast compiled code for `numpy` - the "vectorized" stuff - only works with numeric dtype arrays.  For object dtype it has to do something akin to a list comprehension.  Even when math works, it's because it was able to delegate the action to the elements.

For example applying list replication to all elements of your array:

```
In [7]: array*3                                                                 
Out[7]: 
array([list([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]), list([2, 2, 2]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
```

and `sum` is just list join:

```
In [8]: array.sum()                                                             
Out[8]: [0, 1, 2, 2]
```

`apply_along_axis` isn't an faster than `np.vectorize`.  And I can't imagine how it would be used in a case like this.  `array` is 1d.

Sometimes `frompyfunc` is handy when working with object dtype arrays (but it's not a speed solution):

```
In [11]: timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda a: a[0] if a else None, 1,1)(array)        
3.8 µs ± 9.85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [12]: timeit [a[0] if a else None for a in array]                            
1.02 µs ± 5.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [14]: timeit np.vectorize(lambda a: a[0] if a else None, otypes=['O'])(array)                                                                    
18 µs ± 46.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```